# Mathjax - processing mathematics in div with display:none

Tags: css, mathjax

[Mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) typesets mathematics in a separate location if the content is in a container with display:none because  browser does not compute the sizes of the sub-elements. This causes issues especially with width of elements. [This is explained in detail here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Dealing-with-display:none)

To avoid this, it is suggested to use css like `position: absolute; top: 0, left:0; width:0, height:0, overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;` instead of `display:none`

I do not have much coding experience. My doubt is, can't we just use  `position: absolute;width:0, visibility: hidden;`? From my testing, this itself is fine. Why additional css like  `top: 0, left:0; height:0,overflow: hidden;` though it can further ensure content is hidden? can anyone help to understand? I know what each of this attribute will do, but thinking it is not necessary at all here.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question visibility : hidden is hide the element but it still covered all space of the container as you defined . That ' s why you need to use width :0 height: 0 and you have to use overflow hidden just because the div content are not to be overflowed

Comment: i mentioned why width:0, visibility: hidden; is not enough? width 0 can ensure it is not taking any space and other attributes may not be needed

Comment: Because visibility hidden only hide the element .. not removes the captured place